# How to add Data to RecyclerView in Fragment From Another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment In ViewPager That have a RecyclrView And Button , 
the Button Going To open a New Fragment to Fill Data to display in RecyclerView , I need A way to fetch these data and to display iy in RecyclerView ,

here is the fragment that show recyclerview + button

```
public class ContractPlanFragment extends Fragment implements  PlanRecyclerView.MyClickListener {
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    private RecyclerView planRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private List<Integer> framePhotoList ;
    private Button addPlan ;
    View rootView;
    List<Plan> planList ;
    private static final String ARG_KEY = "key";
    private String mKey;
    private ContractInfoPage mPage;
    private PageFragmentCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private String plan_detials;
    private String palnDate;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;

    public static ContractPlanFragment create(String key) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_KEY, key);

        ContractPlanFragment fragment = new ContractPlanFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ContractPlanFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contract_plan, container, false);
        addPlan = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addNewPlan);
        planRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plan_view);
        planRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        planRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        planRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        planRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES , MODE_PRIVATE);
        plan_detials = prefs.getString("plan_detials", null);
        palnDate = prefs.getString("Date", null);
        startTime = prefs.getString("startTime", null);
        endTime = prefs.getString("endTime", null);
        Log.i("the valu" , palnDate + plan_detials);
        Plan p = new Plan();
        p.setPlanDetails( plan_detials);
        p.setStartTime(palnDate);
        p.setEndTime(startTime);
        p.setPlanDate(endTime);
        planList = new ArrayList<>();

        planList.add(p);
        planList.add(new Plan("تجربة ويا رب تزبط" ,"15/10/2018" ,"08:50" ,"13:20"));
        mAdapter = new PlanRecyclerView(planList , getContext());
        planRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        addPlan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment addPlanFragment = new AddPlanFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.create_contract_layout, addPlanFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
                transaction.commit();




            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (!(activity instanceof PageFragmentCallbacks)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement PageFragmentCallbacks");
        }

        mCallbacks = (PageFragmentCallbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
}
```

and here is the fragment that i fill data in it :

```
public class AddPlanFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView tvDisplayTime;
    private TimePicker timePicker1;
    private DatePicker plan_date;
    View bottomSheetView;
    static EditText addDateText;
    static EditText startTime ;
    private EditText plan_detials_text ;
    Button savePlanBtn ,cancelBtn;
    static EditText endTime;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

    public AddPlanFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_plan, container, false);
        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        addDateText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addDateText) ;
        startTime = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startTime);
        endTime = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.endTime);
        plan_detials_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plan_detials_text);
        savePlanBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.savePlanBtn);
        cancelBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        addDateText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
        }
    });

        startTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment_start();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            }
        });
        endTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment_end();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            }
        });

 cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         getActivity().onBackPressed();
     }
 });
        savePlanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("plan_detials", plan_detials_text.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("Date", addDateText.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("startTime", startTime.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("endTime",endTime.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                Intent go = new Intent(getActivity(),CreateContractActivity.class);

                // you pass the position you want the viewpager to show in the extra,
                // please don't forget to define and initialize the position variable
                // properly
                go.putExtra("viewpager_position", 6);
                startActivity(go);
               // getActivity().onBackPressed();

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public static class  SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
        }
        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            addDateText.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
        }

    }

    public static class TimePickerFragment_start extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            // Get a Calendar instance
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            // Get the current hour and minute
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar,this,hour,minute,false);
            // Return the TimePickerDialog
            return tpd;
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
            // Do something with the returned time
            startTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        }
    }
    public static class TimePickerFragment_end extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            // Get a Calendar instance
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            // Get the current hour and minute
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar,this,hour,minute,false);
            // Return the TimePickerDialog
            return tpd;
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
            // Do something with the returned time
            endTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        }
    }

}
```

and I want a way to back to the same fragment after save data , any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Save data in your fragment in `SavePlanBtn.setOnClickListener` use this code:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("first","Here is your first String");
            args.putString("second" , "Here is your second String");
            Fragment newFragment = new yourFragment();
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // this to back to the first fragment
```

Then to receive the data in your fragment in `onCreateView` method use this:

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
            String one = getArguments().getString("first");
           String two = getArguments().getString("second");
        }
```

**And don't forget to edit this code**:                 `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` 
To:

```
transaction.addToBackStack("string");
```

It is to back to the first fragment.